# Django class with an attribute with different values

Tags: python, django, class

I'm trying to understand how `django` relationships work.

I basically have an `Attribute` class that should have many `Option` instances.
For example, the attribute could be `color = Attribute(name='color')` with loads
of options such as `blue = Option(name='blue', attribute=color)`, or
`green = Option(name='green', attribute=color)`.

So the `models.py` file would look something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Option(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(ProductAttribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    options = models.ForeignKey(ProductOption, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How's best to achieve this please?

Comment: It's not clear if an `Option` can be used for multiple `Attribute` objects. It sounds like not, in which case you only need a ForeignKey `attribute` on the `Option` (and not the other way round!). When you specify a ForeignKey, it's a one-to-many relationship. You automatically get the reverse relationship, please read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships) carefully.

Comment: It looks like you may be implementing what's referred to as an "entity-attribute-value" design. That's usually a recipe for future problems - it performs terribly outside of some specific scenarios. I don't know your specific situation, of course, but it's a common and tempting way to make your present situation simpler but your future a lot harder. See for instance https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios for some discussion.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Thanks for the advice - it would appear that's what I'm doing. Some answers in the thread say it's okay if the `Option` is changing dynamically, i.e. a new colour `pink` is added at a later date?

Comment: Generally if you want a predefined set of options - eg for colour - you either present colour as a string field on the table for the specific product, in which case Django has support for declaring a limited range of choices, or (almost always better) you have a `colour` table and use a foreign key to it. So adding a new colour just means adding a new row to your database of options. I personally wouldn't use it to handle new _values_ coming in unpredictably - even something like a user-entered tag system scales best if you create new `tag` records as needed.

Comment: What I _have_ used it for (knowing the tradeoffs) was for a pure catalog-display solution, in which I knew that a) I had an upstream data provider that would unpredictably add _attributes_ to my product records, and b) it was important to display all the attributes, but (critically) it was not important to search or filter on them. Where E-A-V really falls down is when you want to do queries like "show me all products that have this value for this attribute" - easy to imagine if you think of entities that have a publisher or manufacturer as an attribute.